# wmode transparency?

Tags: flash, wmode

Could someone tell me why the dropdown menu isn't displaying above the flash object in Internet Explorer.

I was under the impression that all that was required was wmode='transparent'. This was working previously but not currently.

URL here.

http://clubentertainment.ie/entertainment/

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` in the flash movies object tag.  Have you done this and if so checked this in IE?